# Executing a command with multiple parameters in bash

Tags: linux, bash, checkpoint

I am trying to execute a command with multiple parameters in a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
read a[{1..3}] <<< $(echo /opt/CPshrd-R77/bin/cpview history off); echo "${a[1]} ${a[2]} ${a[3]}"
#"/opt/CPshrd-R77/bin/cpview history off"

for (( i =0 ; i < ${#a[@]} ; i++ ))
do
        printf "\n Running '$(a[$1]}' \n\n"
        eval "${a[$i]}"
done
```

I hacked together this script from a couple examples on stackoverflow.  What is happening is the cpview utility is being called instead of the full command terminating the history.  Cpview is a Check Point utility used to display CPU, Memory, network stats, firewall performance, etc.  Its buggy and it has a memory leak, so I need to shut it off.

Comment: Why do you need all this script for running `/opt/CPshrd-R77/bin/cpview history off` command?

Comment: ...there's a lot that's wrong in here, but it almost doesn't seem worth tearing it down piece-by-piece; the answers to those issues generally fall into the category of "don't do that".

Comment: (I mean, that in the world is the possible use of `read a[{1..3}] <<< $(echo /opt/CPshrd-R77/bin/cpview history off)`? I can't conceive of a scenario where it would be more correct than `read -a a <<<"/opt/CPshrd-R77/bin/cpview history off"`, even if you *did* want to read each word in a command into a separate array element... but there's also no obvious reason why you need an array at all. And evaluating each word in that array as if it were a separate command? Why would that ever be useful?)

Comment: ...I mean, seriously, why *isn't* your script just one line after the shebang, that line being `/opt/CPshrd-R77/bin/cpview history off`?

Answer (score -1):

Turns out that this was caused by the cpview binary.  I worked around the issue by running a bash script to kill the process.